# Impute missing and outlier values as median, excluding the outliers from the calculation of the median

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, data-cleaning

## Impute the median for both missing values and extreme values, excluding those extremes from the calculation of the median.

I want to impute using the median. I want to calculate the median excluding the extremes. I then want to impute these extremes as the median value.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"AAA":[100,NaN,0.0,0.1,4.6]})

   AAA
0  100
1  NaN
2  0.0
3  0.1
4  4.6
```

I want to define observation index=`0` as an outlier and therefore, exclude it from the imputation calculation, and impute it's value.

```
   AAA  impute
0  100    True
1  NaN    True
2  0.0   False
3  0.1   False
4  4.6   False
```

I then want to impute the values for the NaNs in the new `AAA_` column

```
   AAA  impute  AAA_
0  100    True   NaN
1  NaN    True   NaN
2  0.0   False   0.0
3  0.1   False   0.1
4  4.6   False   4.6
```

I therefore want a dataframe like the following:

```
   AAA  impute  AAA_
0  100    True   0.1
1  NaN    True   0.1
2  0.0   False   0.0
3  0.1   False   0.1
4  4.6   False   4.6
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Define observation index=`0` as an outlier and therefore, exclude it.

We first calculate the outliers in `df["AAA"]` as separate boolean arrays (with the same length as the original Series).

```
outlier = np.where(df["AAA"] >= 100,1,0).astype(bool)
is_null = np.where(df["AAA"].isnull(),1,0).astype(bool)
impute = (outlier | is_null)
```

This returns the following result as a dataframe.

```
df["impute"] = impute

   AAA  impute
0  100    True
1  NaN    True
2  0.0   False
3  0.1   False
4  4.6   False
```

#### 2. create a feature vector using only the valid values

Then create a new feature vector for the values which we will use for imputing. This is a subset of `AAA` depending on whether it was flagged as an outlier or missing.

```
AAA_=np.where(~impute, x.AAA, np.nan)

df["AAA_"] = AAA_

   AAA  impute  AAA_
0  100    True   NaN
1  NaN    True   NaN
2  0.0   False   0.0
3  0.1   False   0.1
4  4.6   False   4.6
```

#### 3. Impute the values

You then can impute the values using scikit-learn's `preprocessing.Imputer`.

```
median_imputer = preprocessing.Imputer(strategy="median", axis=0)
AAA_complete = median_imputer.fit_transform(AAA_.reshape(-1, 1))
```

This returns the answer:

```
df["AAA"] = AAA_complete

   AAA  impute  AAA_
0  100    True   0.1
1  NaN    True   0.1
2  0.0   False   0.0
3  0.1   False   0.1
4  4.6   False   4.6
```

Note: I am aware that median is robust in the face of extreme values, but I want these values to be transformed too. This could easily be changed to the mean by changing one line. `median_imputer = preprocessing.Imputer(strategy="median", axis=0)` to `mean_imputer = preprocessing.Imputer(strategy="mean", axis=0)`